# Prevent Windows from passing login credentials to Samba server

Tags: windows, authentication, samba

When I'm trying to access some share from windows explorer, it's sending my current login/password to remote server and im getting access denied, because, for example, my local and remote usernames are identical, but passwords are different.

Is there a way to completely disable this 'feature'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via GPO or local security policy on your machine, you can configure "Network security: Restrict NTLM: Outgoing NTLM traffic to remote servers"

`Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Network security: Restrict NTLM: Outgoing NTLM traffic to remote servers`

> If you select "Deny all," the client computer cannot authenticate identities to a remote server by using NTLM authentication. You can use the "Network security: Restrict NTLM: Add remote server exceptions for NTLM authentication" policy setting to define a list of remote servers to which clients are allowed to use NTLM authentication.
>   This policy is supported on at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

You could also explicitly "net use" a share on the Samba server using the correct credentials, which would avoid sending the bad ones.